# tela edição usuário não carrega dados, e método excluir não exclui

Tags: primefaces, hibernate, jpa, cdi

Dê uma olhada nos códigos:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Cadastro de Usuário</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">
        <h:form>

            <h1>Cadastro Usuário</h1>

            <f:metadata>
                <o:viewParam name="usuario" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario}"/>
                <f:event listener="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.inicializar}" type="preRenderView" />
            </f:metadata>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

            <p:toolbar>
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:button value="Novo" outcome="CadastroUsuario"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar" action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.salvar}"  update="@form"/>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="pesquisa"/>                    
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style=" width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo" >

                <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
                <p:inputText id="nome" size="60" maxlength="80" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.nome}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="E-mail" for="email"/>
                <p:inputText id="email" size="60" maxlength="80" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.email}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Senha" for="senha"/>
                <p:password id="senha" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.senha}"/>

                <p:selectOneMenu >                
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Auxiliar"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Vandedor"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Administradores"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>          

                <p:commandButton value="Adicionar grupo"/>
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:dataTable value="#{pesquisaClienteBean.itens}" var="item" id="tabelaItens" style="margin-top: 20px">

                <p:column headerText="Grupo" style="text-align: left">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendedor"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column   style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" oncomplete="PF('comfirmacaoExclusao').show();"/>
                </p:column >

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:confirmDialog header="Exclusao Usuário" message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir Usuário"
                             widgetVar="comfirmacaoExclusao">
                <p:button value="Não" onclick="PF('comfirmacaoExclusao').hide(); return false;"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="PF('comfirmacaoExclusao').hide();"/>

            </p:confirmDialog>

        </h:form>  
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

**CadastroUsuarioBean.java**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroUsuarioBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private Usuario usuario;

    private Grupo grupoSelecionado;
    private List<Grupo> grupo = new ArrayList<Grupo>();

    @Inject
    private CadastroUsuarioService cadastroUsuarioService;

    @Inject
    private Grupos grupos;

    public CadastroUsuarioBean() {
        limpar();
    }

    public void inicializar() {
        grupo = grupos.grupos();
        grupoSelecionado = new Grupo();
    }

    public void limpar() {
        usuario = new Usuario();
        grupo = new ArrayList<Grupo>();
    }

    public void salvar() {

        adicionarGrupo();
        this.usuario = cadastroUsuarioService.salvar(this.usuario);

        limpar();
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Usuario cadastro com sucesso!");
    }

    public void adicionarGrupo() {
        this.usuario.getGrupos().add(grupoSelecionado);
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public List<Grupo> getGrupo() {
        return grupo;
    }

    public Grupo getGrupoSelecionado() {
        return grupoSelecionado;
    }

    public void setGrupoSelecionado(Grupo grupoSelecionado) {
        this.grupoSelecionado = grupoSelecionado;
    }
}
```

**CadastroUSuaroService.java**

```
 public class CadastroUsuarioService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    @Inject
    private Usuarios usuarios;

    @Transactional
    public Usuario salvar(Usuario usuario) {
        Usuario usuarioExistente = usuarios.porId(usuario.getId());

        if (usuarioExistente != null && !usuarioExistente.equals(usuario)) {
            throw new NegocioException("Já existe um usuario informado.");
        }

        return usuarios.guardar(usuario);
    }

}
```

**UsuarioConverter.java**

```
    @FacesConverter(forClass = Usuario.class)
public class UsuarioConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private Usuarios usuarios;

    public UsuarioConverter() {
        usuarios = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(Usuarios.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Usuario retorno = null;

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
            retorno = (Usuario) this.usuarios.filtrados(new UsuarioFilter());
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            Long id = ((Usuario) value).getId();
            String retorno = (id == null ? null : id.toString());

            return retorno;
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

**repositorio Usuarios.java**

```
    public class Usuarios implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Usuario guardar(Usuario usuario) {
        return manager.merge(usuario);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void remover(Usuario usuario) {
        try {
            usuario = porId(usuario.getId());
            manager.remove(usuario);
            manager.flush();
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new NegocioException("Usuario " + usuario.getNome() + " não pode ser excluído.");
        }
    }

    /*public Usuario porId(Long id) {
     return manager.find(Usuario.class, id);
     }*/
    public Usuario porId(Long id) {
        try {
            return manager.createQuery("from Usuario where id = :id", Usuario.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Usuario porNomeOuEmail(String nome, String email) {
        try {
            return manager.createQuery("from Usuario where upper(nome) = :nome and email = :email", Usuario.class)
                    .setParameter("nome", nome.toUpperCase())
                    .setParameter("email", email.toUpperCase())
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Usuario porEmail(String email) {
        try {
            return manager.createQuery("from Usuario where upper(email) = :email", Usuario.class)
                    .setParameter("email", email.toUpperCase())
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Usuario> filtrados(UsuarioFilter filtro) {
        Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filtro.getNome())) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nome", filtro.getNome(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        }

        return criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("nome")).list();
    }
}
```

**repositorio grupos.java**

```
 public class Grupos implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public List<Grupo> grupos(){
        return manager.createQuery("FROM Grupo",Grupo.class).getResultList();
    }

    public  Grupo porId(Long id) {
        return this.manager.find(Grupo.class, id);
    }


    public Grupo grupoPorNome(String nome)
    {
        try
            {
            return manager.createQuery("from Grupo where upper(nome) = :nome", Grupo.class)
                    .setParameter("nome", nome.toUpperCase())
                    .getSingleResult();
            }
        catch (NoResultException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

PesquisaUsuarioBean.java

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PesquisaUsuariosBean implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

@Inject
private Usuarios usuarios;

private final UsuarioFilter filtro;
private List<Usuario> usuariosFiltrados;

private Usuario usuarioSelecionado;

public PesquisaUsuariosBean() {
    filtro = new UsuarioFilter();
}

public void excluir() {
    usuarios.remover(usuarioSelecionado);
    usuariosFiltrados.remove(usuarioSelecionado);

    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Usuario" + usuarioSelecionado.getId() + "excluido com sucesso");

}

public void pesquisar() {
    usuariosFiltrados = usuarios.filtrados(filtro);
}

public UsuarioFilter getFiltro() {
    return filtro;
}

public List<Usuario> getUsuariosFiltrados() {
    return usuariosFiltrados;
}



public Usuario getUsuarioSelecionado() {
    return usuarioSelecionado;
}

public void setUsuarioSelecionado(Usuario usuarioSelecionado) {
    this.usuarioSelecionado = usuarioSelecionado;
}
```

}

PesquisaUsuarios.xhtml

```
    <ui:define name="corpo">
    <h:form >
        <h1>Pesquisa Usuarios</h1>

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

        <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">

            <p:toolbarGroup style="padding: 4px">
                <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" action="#{pesquisaUsuariosBean.pesquisar}"
                                 update=" @form "  />
            </p:toolbarGroup>

            <p:toolbarGroup align="right" style="padding: 4px"> 
                <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/usuarios/CadastroUsuario" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>

        </p:toolbar>

        <p:panelGrid  id="painel" columns="2" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo,campo">

            <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
            <p:inputText id="nome" style="width: 50%" value="#{pesquisaUsuariosBean.filtro.nome}"/>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:dataTable value="#{pesquisaUsuariosBean.usuariosFiltrados}" var="usuario" id="tabelaUsuarios" style="margin-top: 20px"
                     emptyMessage="Nenhum Usuario Encontrado" rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginatorPosition="bottom">

            <p:column headerText="Nome" style="text-align: left">
                <h:outputText value="#{usuario.nome}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="E-mail"  style="text-align: left">
                <h:outputText value="#{usuario.email}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column   style="width: 100px;text-align: center">
                <p:button  icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" style="margin: 5px"
                           outcome="/usuarios/CadastroUsuario">
                    <f:param name="usuario" value="#{usuario.id}"/>
                </p:button>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').show()" process="@this"
                                 update=":confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pesquisaUsuariosBean.usuarioSelecionado}" value="#{usuario}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column >

        </p:dataTable>

        <p:confirmDialog header="Exclusão de produto" message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto #{pesquisaUsuariosBean.usuarioSelecionado.nome} ?"
                         widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao" id="confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
            <p:button value="Não" onclick="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide(); return false;" />
            <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide();" 
                             action="#{pesquisaUsuariosBean.excluir}" process="@this" update="@from"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>

    </h:form>
```

Comment: log aparece este erro tambem:

Comment: Olá, Adriano! Detalhe melhor seu erro. não ficou claro em que ponto dá o erro e os detalhes do erro.

Comment: Olá Dherik, este problema conseguir resolver,estou com outro problema ao editar e excluir, ao acionar botão editar ele direciona para tela de cadastro que eu estou usando para cadastro e edição, mais a mesma não está carregando dados para tela cadastro, pois quando aciono editar direcionar é para carregar dados na tela de cadastro para edição, e ao excluir diz que usuário não poder excluído. já tentei inúmeras possibilidades e nada. vou postar código. se poder me ajudar te agradeço.

Comment: se resolveu o problema, mostre a solução aqui para nós. Se tem uma nova dúvida, recomendo criar uma nova pergunta :).

Comment: Dherik me desculpe, me  enganei não resolvi ainda este problema ainda persiste no log do servidor mostra que  está acessando banco mas não aparece na tela, id da consulta aparece mas não carrega dados, e não consigo excluir.

Comment: olá alguém pode me ajudar